# Changing Case with Exception Specifically in between dollar signs

Tags: python-2.7, casing

**Input:**

```
MECR-tree obtained using \textbf{MCAR-Miner} with $S_{\mathrm{U}}  = data$ 25{\%} and $S_{\mathrm{L}}  = string$ 12.5{\%}
```

Change it to Title Case but exempt the text within the $ signs.

**Output should be:**

```
Mecr-Tree Obtained Using \textbf{Mcar-Miner} With $S_{\mathrm{U}}  = data$ 25{\%} And $S_{\mathrm{L}}  = string$ 12.5{\%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that assumes that the `$` character will always occur in pairs:

```
sp = s.split('$')
for i, seg in enumerate(sp):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sp[i] = seg.title()

print('$'.join(sp))
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
print(r'$'.join([seg.title() if not i % 2 else seg for i, seg in enumerate(s.split('$'))]))
```